# Why does my function pointer code run with no errors?

Tags: c++, pointers, function

I have this:

```
typedef void (*funcptr) (void);

int main(){

    funcptr(); //this can compile and run with no error . WHAT DOES IT MEAN? WHY NO ERRORS?


}
```

Comment: Try to give your questions titles that actually tell us what you're asking. That way it's easier for people to find and answer the question, and others who have a similar question might be able to find it and read the existing answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The statement creates a `funcptr` instance by its default constructor* and discard it.

It is just similar to the code

```
int main () {
    double();
}
```

---

<sub>(Note: * Technically it performs *default-initialization* as not all types have constructors. Those types will return the default value (*zero-initialized*), e.g. 0. See C++98 §5.2.3/2 and §8.5/5 for what actually happens.)</sub>

Comment: are you saying there are default constructors for all types? including primitive types and user defined types e.g. a type from typedef ?

Comment: @John: All primitive types have a default-constructor, yes. User defined-types with at least one user-defined constructor don't have a default constructor unless one is defined explicitly. And the poorly named `typedef` does not define a type but merely introduce a type synonym. After `typedef double foo`, the expressions `double()` and `foo()` are equivalent.

Comment: Not correct. Only class types have constructors. Non-class types have no constructors. The expression in the OP, as well as `double()` expression has absolutely nothing to do with any constructors. The result of this expression is specified by the language standard without involving any constructors.

Comment: I just tried (int*) (); which gives me an compilation error, but typedef int* intptr; and then intptr(); becomes legal. I think it's not quite just a synonym, agree?

Comment: @Johnyy: The syntax that you are using is formally a form of functional cast. In functional casts, the type name must consist of only one token. So, for example, you can't immediately use `int *`, and you can't use `unsigned int` in functional casts. But if you create a typedef name for the type, you'll be able to use it, since it becomes one token.

Comment: @AndreyT: Do you have any reference for your claim that `int` has no constructor? I'm pretty sure Bjarne Stroustrup explains in *The Design And Evolution of C++* why he introduced constructors for scalar types, but unfortunately, I don't have the book here right now.

Comment: @FredOverflow: The wording used in TC++PL is a well-known [deliberate] error. AFAIK, this was done to simplify the explanation. But formally speaking what Stroustrup states in this respect in TC++PL is plain incorrect. Only class types in C++ have constructors. That's how the language is defined. (The standard doesn't state it literally, i.e. there's no place in the document that would say exactly that, but nevertheless it is the case.)

Comment: @FredOverflow: I hope you realize that if type `double` really had a default constructor, that constructor would have to be invoked for any automatic variable declared as `double d;`, i.e. every automatic variable would be implicitly zero-initialized. Yet, it doesn't happen. Any automatic variable declared as `double d;` contains garbage.

Comment: @Andrey: Thanks for your explanations. I stand corrected then.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I just noticed that you were talking about D&E, not about TC++PL. I don't have my copy of D&E here, but I'd guess that what Stroustrup meant was a *uniform syntax for initialization* for all types, not the actual constructors.

Comment: @Andrey: So `42` and `int(42)` are different beasts? The former denotes a value, the latter a temporary object? `(int)42` and `static_cast<int>(42)` also denote temporary objects? Just asking to be sure.

Comment: @FredOverflow: See my comments under my own answer. I'm probably wrong to claim that `int()` is a temporary. The correct term is *rvalue*. Temporaries of scalar types do exist, but one need to take some extra steps to create them. A mere `int()` is not enough.

Comment: @Andrey: My impression is that the only context in which a temporary object of scalar type is created is when binding an rvalue to a reference (either an lvalue reference to const or an rvalue reference), something which rarely occurs in non-generic code. Would you agree?

Comment: @FredOverflow: That's the only context I can think of too.

Answer (score 5):

In C++ language, any expression of the form `some_type()` creates a value of type `some_type`. The value is *value-initialized*.

For example, expression `int()` creates a value-initialized value of type `int`. Value-initialization for `int` means zero initialization, meaning that `int()` evaluates to compile-time integer zero.

The same thing happens in your example. You created a value-initialized value of type `funcptr`. For pointer types, value-initialization means initialization with null-pointer.

(Note also, that it is absolutely incorrect to say that expressions like `int()`, `double()` or the one in your OP with non-class types use "default constructors". Non-class types have no constructors. The concept of *initialization* for non-class types is defined by the language specification without involving any "constructors".)

In other words, you are not really "playing with function pointer" in your code sample. You are *creating* a null function pointer value, but you are not doing anything else with it, which is why the code does not exhibit any problems. If you wanted to attempt a call through that function pointer, it would look as follows `funcptr()()` (note two pairs of `()`), and this code would most certainly crash, since that's what usually happens when one attempts a call through a null function pointer value.

Comment: There is no such thing as a temporary object of scalar type. `int()` denotes the *value* zero, not a temporary object bound to that value.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Yes, there is. You must be thinking about C, where th term *object* is synonymous with *lvalue*. In C++ the situation is totaly different. For example, this code `const int &r = int()` attaches the reference to a *temporary object of type `int`*. It is true that `int()` is an *rvalue*, but to claim that there's no temporary objects of scalar types is plain incorrect.

Comment: @Fred: If I'm understanding you, you're saying this should work: `template <int I> struct foo {}; foo<int()>;`? Andrey is correct.

Comment: @Andrey: Section 12.2 "Temporary Objects" starts with "Temporaries *of class type* are created in various contexts". I can't find any reference to temporaries of scalar type in the standard. Please enlighten me :)

Comment: @FredOverflow: Well, as I said, for example 8.5.3/5 at the very end refers to temporaries of non-class types in the rules of const-reference initialization. See the example there as well.

Comment: @GMan: Interesting, yet `int array[int()];` works perfectly, that is, gives an error message about zero-sized arrays :)

Comment: @Fred: On what compiler? Hopefully not GCC with extensions...(hint: VLA?)

Comment: @GMan: g++ 4.5.0 without extensions. `int i = 0; int array[i];` gives an error related to VLAs.

Comment: @Fred: Well I'm at a loss then. :) @Andrey? :P

Comment: @GMan: I don't understand the intent of your template example. I's say that it should work. `int()` is an integral constant expression, isn't it? In fact, I think I might be wrong to say that `some_type()` immediately creates a temporary for any type. It actually creates an *rvalue*, which is not necessarily a temporary object. Temporaries of scalar types do exist, but `int()` alone probably does not create one by itself. `const int &r = int()` does, but a mere `int()` doesn't.

Comment: @AndreyT: Is it? Heh, I honestly haven't a clue, I never thought it would be. Comeau accepts it, but VS and gcc don't. Seems it is, I was wrong.

Comment: @Andrey: As GMan says, `foo<int()>();` does not compile on g++ 4.5.0, but if you explicitly cast the argument to `int`, it works: `foo<(int)(int())>();`. I think I should take a break now :)

Comment: @FredOverflow: Interesting. It compiles fine in Comeau. Does that mean that a `int a[int() + 1]` is a VLA in GCC, i.e. GCC would accept it in C++ code only because it allows VLA in C++ code?

Comment: @Andrey: I find it funny how even 12 years after standardization, compiler writers still get fundamentals such as these wrong :) And no, `int array[int() + 1];` compiles fine without any VLA extensions.

Comment: @AndreyT why is `funcptr()()` suppose to work? Isn't it similar to `double()()`?

Comment: @user25464: Well, yes and no. Expression `T()()` (where `T` is a type) creates a temporary object `T()` of type `T` and then applies operator `()` to it. In that sense `funcptr()()` is similar to `double()()`. But that's where similarity ends. If you do `double()()` you'll get a compile error, since you are trying to apply operator `()` to an object of type `double`. This is illegal. When you do `funcptr()()`, you are applying operator `()` to an object of  function pointer type, which is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a datatype, funcptr, which is a function that takes no parameters and returns void. You are then creating an instance of it, but without an identifier, discarding it.